# Cloudfront fails to redirect from http to https (when called from the server); Causing mixed-content-

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-cloudfront

***Context***: I have a 3rd party application running in an EC2 instance via HTTP, and a Cloudfront distribution placed infront for caching and to serve the app via HTTPS.

***Website URL***: https://elvis.********.com

***Problem***: I don't have much control over the 3rd party application - but it makes an api call to my app via http. Since the website is hosted over https, this causes an error `blocked:mixed-content`

[image: blocked:mixed-content]

(The 3rd party app makes a server call to itself, but via http - See Request URL and Origin)
[image]

In this case, shouldn't Cloudfront route this to API call from HTTP to HTTPS? It is a call to the same URL & Server after all.

Wondering if adding a Lambda@Edge function would help (viewer-request | viewer-response | origin-request | origin-response?). But i'm quite skeptical as it looks like the browser blocks the request immediately.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: naribo, CloudFront redirects http to https if the request is received by it, however, in your case, the browser sees href etc link as http and doesn't even try to contact to this cloudfront and blocks it, you need to make sure that you hardcode the url on https.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help but try to add hsts info for this domain in chrome chrome://net-internals/#hsts

Answer (score 0):

Cloudfront does not do the protocol switching or delegation. This error is coming from the browser and it clearly says it does not allow mixed content. To fix this, you need to host your endpoint on https. If you are using AWS for your endpoint hosting, then it is easy to set up a load balancer with HTTPS certificate. Or you can set up another Cloudfront endpoint for your application origin.

Comment: Hi Juned! My endpoint is already hosted on https via AWS cloudformation.
The 3rd party application simply calls the endpoint with "http" (Have no way to change it to "https"). 

How does cloudfront redirect from http to https in the browser, but not for a server call?